# ActionPerformed method stops working when making an interna method call

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm new to java and trying to learn it better by making a "slot machine"
Basically, my actionPerformed method for the "Spinbutton" where it relocates the labels that have Icons on them stops working when I make an internal method call to the andraBalans() method (its used to change the balance of every spin).
How can I solve this?

```
 private void andraBalans()
 {
    int spelSumma = (int) betSize.getValue();
    int nySumma = Integer.parseInt(balance.getText());
    int nySumma2 = nySumma - spelSumma;

    balance.setText(Integer.toString(nySumma2));
  }

   private void spinActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     


    andraBalans();


    int slumpatTal = randomg.nextInt(6) + 1;
    int slumpatTal2 = randomg.nextInt(6) + 1;
    int slumpatTal3 = randomg.nextInt(6) + 1;

    //Slumpa för Reel 1
    if (slumpatTal == 1) {
        rad1lbl1.setLocation(46, 50);
        rad1lbl2.setLocation(46, 192);
        rad1lbl3.setLocation(46, 348);

    } else if (slumpatTal == 2) {
        rad1lbl1.setLocation(46, 192);
        rad1lbl2.setLocation(46, 50);
        rad1lbl3.setLocation(46, 348);
    } else if (slumpatTal == 3) {
        rad1lbl1.setLocation(46, 348);
        rad1lbl2.setLocation(46, 192);
        rad1lbl3.setLocation(46, 50);
    } else if (slumpatTal == 4) {
        rad1lbl1.setLocation(46, 192);
        rad1lbl2.setLocation(46, 50);
        rad1lbl3.setLocation(46, 348);
    } else if (slumpatTal == 5) {
        rad1lbl1.setLocation(46, 50);
        rad1lbl2.setLocation(46, 348);
        rad1lbl3.setLocation(46, 192);
    } else if (slumpatTal == 6) {
        rad1lbl1.setLocation(46, 50);
        rad1lbl2.setLocation(46, 192);
        rad1lbl3.setLocation(46, 348);
    }

    //Slumpa för Reel 2
    if (slumpatTal2 == 1) {
        rad2lbl1.setLocation(273, 50);
        rad2lbl2.setLocation(273, 189);
        rad2lbl3.setLocation(273, 348);
    } else if (slumpatTal2 == 2) {
        rad2lbl1.setLocation(273, 189);
        rad2lbl2.setLocation(273, 50);
        rad2lbl3.setLocation(273, 348);
    } else if (slumpatTal2 == 3) {
        rad2lbl1.setLocation(273, 189);
        rad2lbl2.setLocation(273, 348);
        rad2lbl3.setLocation(273, 50);
    } else if (slumpatTal2 == 4) {
        rad2lbl1.setLocation(273, 348);
        rad2lbl2.setLocation(273, 50);
        rad2lbl3.setLocation(273, 189);
    } else if (slumpatTal2 == 5) {
        rad2lbl1.setLocation(273, 50);
        rad2lbl2.setLocation(273, 348);
        rad2lbl3.setLocation(273, 189);
    } else if (slumpatTal2 == 6) {
        rad2lbl1.setLocation(273, 348);
        rad2lbl2.setLocation(273, 189);
        rad2lbl3.setLocation(273, 50);

    }

    //Slumpa för Reel 3
    if (slumpatTal3 == 1) {
        rad3lbl1.setLocation(492, 50);
        rad3lbl2.setLocation(492, 187);
        rad3lbl3.setLocation(492, 348);
    } else if (slumpatTal3 == 2) {
        rad3lbl1.setLocation(492, 50);
        rad3lbl2.setLocation(492, 348);
        rad3lbl3.setLocation(492, 187);
    } else if (slumpatTal3 == 3) {
        rad3lbl1.setLocation(492, 348);
        rad3lbl2.setLocation(492, 50);
        rad3lbl3.setLocation(492, 187);
    } else if (slumpatTal3 == 4) {
        rad3lbl1.setLocation(492, 348);
        rad3lbl2.setLocation(492, 187);
        rad3lbl3.setLocation(492, 50);
    } else if (slumpatTal3 == 5) {
        rad3lbl1.setLocation(492, 187);
        rad3lbl2.setLocation(492, 50);
        rad3lbl3.setLocation(492, 348);
    } else if (slumpatTal3 == 6) {
        rad3lbl1.setLocation(492, 187);
        rad3lbl2.setLocation(492, 348);
        rad3lbl3.setLocation(492, 50);
    }
```

Comment: What does "stops working" mean? Does you program crash? Does it freeze? Be specific in your descriptions, or it becomes difficult to help you. You may wish to include some more of your code, specifically, how you're using your custom  `spinActionPerformed` event. Usually, you would be listening for a button click event or some other orthodox event, so I think the conceptualization of your program bears examination.

Comment: @MarsAtomic It stops putting the jLabels on random locations when I put andraBalans() in the actionperfored method, all the method does is change the balance on every spin. It works perfectly fine when I dont use the andraBalans method.